# CSS ::after Adding Ring Shape

Tags: css

I'm looking to add a CSS shape after a div of content.

The shape will be a ring: so, a circle with a hole in the middle.

```
.name::after {
    content: '';
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.name.track-1::after {
    border-color: #0065FF;
}

.name.track-2::after {
    border-color: #FFC300;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to apply a basic style `::after` `.name` then when it's accompanied by additional classes like `.track-1` or `.track-2` it will be different colors.

I am seeing nothing show up though. I've also tried the CSS2 `:after`, no luck. I've tried putting `border-color` into the main `.name::after` with no luck. Any help would be great, thank you!

**EDIT** HTML was requested:

```
<div class="name track-1">This is the name of something here</div>
```

Comment: add `content` property and provide HTML also so we can solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify a `display: block` property on `.name::after`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Also, I'm a dumb-dumb and mispelled a class name during selection, like `.this-thing .name` vs `.this-things .name`.